# Text search of a many-to-many data relation

Tags: sql, t-sql, many-to-many

I know this must have been answered before here, but I simply can't find a matching question.

Using a `LIKE '%keyword%'`, I want to search a many-to-many data relationship in a MSSQL database and reduce it to a one-to-one result set. The two tables are joined through a linking table. Here's a very simplified version of what I'm talking about:

```
Books:
book_ id  title
1         Treasure Island
2         Poe Collected Stories
3         Invest in Treasure Islands

Categories:
category_id  name
1            Children
2            Adventure
3            Horror
4            Classic
5            Money

BookCategory:
book_id   category_id
1         1
1         2
1         4
2         3
2         4
3         5
```

What I want to do is search for a phrase in the title (e.g. `'%treasure island%'`) and get matching Books records that contain the search string and the single highest matching `Categories` record that goes with each book -- I want to discard the lesser category records. In other words, I'm looking for this:

```
book_id  title                       category_id  name
1        Treasure Island             4            Classic
3        Invest in Treasure Islands  5            Money
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Filter your lookup table, then join:

```
With maxCategories AS
 (select book_id, max(category_id) as category_id from BookCategory group by book_id)
select Books.book_id, Books.Title, Categories.category_id, Categories.name
from Books 
inner join maxCategories on (Books.book_id = maxCategories.book_id)
inner join Categories on (Categories.category_id = maxCategories.category_id)
where Books.title like '%treasure island%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * from
(select b.*, 
        c.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by bc.book_id 
                           order by bc.category_id desc) rn
 from Books b
 join BookCategory bc on b.book_id = bc.book_id
 join Categories c on bc.category_id = c.category_id
 where b.name like '%treasure island%') sq
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer! Both your answer and @N West's answer gave me exactly what I wanted and after testing both pretty thoroughly, I can't see a speed difference (the data sample I have isn't very big, so maybe performance issues won't appear yet). So both answers seem equivalent, but since @N West is newer to the community, I'm giving him (or her) the check mark. Again, thanks very much!